# SSL error when adding Stripe Apple Pay button to a ionic mobile app

Tags: ssl, mobile, ionic-framework, stripe-connect, applepay

I'm trying to add Stripe Apple Pay button to a ionic -v1 project. 
https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay/web
But it gives me an error "To use Apple Pay, you must serve your page over HTTPS" in the console.
Do anyone know how to implement Stripe Apple pay button in ionic app?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to set up an SSL certificate for your webpage. Given that you're getting that error, the stripe library is loading. Your problem is that it will refuse to run if not over a secure connection.

You might want to check out something like https://certbot.eff.org/